# PHP script runs fine, just not via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, status

I have a PHP script on my EC2 instance that works perfectly, just to show you here is the output when I run it straight from my browser:
[image]

But when I try to grab it via AJAX, it won't work.  Here is my JavaScript code:

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/mypage/proxy.php",
        data: {symbol: symbol,
             which_website: "yahoo", 
             host_name: "finance.yahoo.com",
             company_name: yahooCompanyName,
             ten_day_volume: yahoo10DayVolume, 
             total_volume: totalVolume, 
             yesterday_volume: yesterdayVolume
             },  
        async: false, 
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        success:  function (data) {

              // etc...
         },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        alert(msg);
    }
```

It always comes back with the "Not connect.\n Verify Network."

If I look at my network response, it looks like the response gets trucated:

[image]

Do I have to configure my browser or something?

Comment: Is it a cross domain ajax call? If so may be proper cors headers not setup in php(server side ec2 instance)?

Comment: That's right, it is.  The JavaScript is executing on my old webserver, calling a PHP script on my EC2 server somewhere else.

Comment: Please take a look at about setting headers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1922960